# What is the difference between a dielectric and a semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, dielectric

It would be very nice if you could give an equation to discern the two material classes.

Please do not provide an answer which is based on the band gap size, since in the last years also diamond (which has a large band-gap) can be seen as a semiconductor, depending on the field you are working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please do not provide an answer which is based on the band gap size, since in the last years also diamond (which has a large band-gap) can be seen as a semiconductor, depending on the field you are working in.

Unfortunately for your request, it turns out that the key quantity to decide if a material is an insulator or a semiconductor is very often the band gap **and** the thermodynamic conditions. Even typical semiconductors like Si or Ge, at very low temperature behave like insulators.

Of course, one has to take into account that among the thermodynamc conditions, in addition to the obvious temperature and pressure values, one has to include also electric and magnetic fields. This remark should make understandable why, besides *external* parameters, the only intrinsic property of a material which really matters remains the band structure and in particular the band gap.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between an insulator and a dielectric?

Comment: Usually they mean the same class of materials. Insulator refers more to the absence of electric conduction, while dielectric to the kind of response the material shows in presence of an electric field (electric polarization).

Answer (score 1):

No equations necessary. A dielectric is always an insulator. A semiconductor can be an insulator or a conductor depending on conditions such as whether an electric field is present. For example a transistor can be used as a switch by applying a voltage across it or not. If the voltage is on it allows current to flow and if the voltage is off it doesn’t.

Comment: @cerv21, you can apply an infinitely large electric field?

Comment: @ Richard: So for a dielectric I can apply an infinite large electric field and it stays insulating? So what is the difference between a dielectric and an insulator? @AlfredCentauri: No, but intensities of the order of 10^16W/cm^2

Comment: You obviously can't apply a near-infinite voltage to an insulator and not have it "break down", but this is an uncontrollable/destructive process, whereas the mechanisms involved with semiconductors are controllable.

Comment: For an ideal dielectric, yes you can apply any voltage you want and it will remain an insulator. Of course no real material is an ideal dielectric.  Real dielectrics “break down” (become conductors) at high enough voltages. A natural example is air breaking down which causes lightning.